# Request only row one from text area?

Tags: php, html, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put string in array, split by new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line)

Is it possible when using the `$_REQUEST['']`  to only request one row from a text area?

Something like:

```
<?php 

  $text = $_REQUEST['originalText']; 

?>

<textarea name="firstRow" rows="5" cols="50" wrap="OFF" ><?php 
    echo $text
?></textarea>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" name="editText">
  <input name="submit" value="Edit Text" type="submit"><br>
  <textarea name="originalText" rows="5" cols="50" wrap="OFF"></textarea>
</form>
```

Instead of `echo $text` is it possible to echo just the first row of `$text`?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck at? Have you searched here on the site?

Comment: I don't know where to start, Ive got it so I get the whole textarea to the new textarea (code above) but I don't know how to just move the first row over, instead of the whole thing.

Comment: http://php.net/string and http://php.net/strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you mean by first row, but if you want to get the first line (before an "enter") do the following:

```
list($first_line) = explode("\n", $text, 2);
```

Or alternatively (and preferably):

```
$first_line = strstr($text, "\n", true);
```

See [`strtr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strtr) and [Demo](http://3v4l.org/Wr3Pa) - you might want to add a `"\n"` to the `$text` to ensure at least one line exists.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks ill accept answer in 6mins

Comment: @DanielX2010: I edited your answer to show usage of a more fitting PHP function and streamlined your explode example.

Comment: @hakre Very nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code works too.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['text'])){
    $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
    $line1 = strpos($text, "\n");
    if($line1 !== false){
        echo substr($text, 0, $line1);
    } else {
        echo $text;
    }
    exit;
 }
?>
<form>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```