# Return specific line of command unix php

Tags: php, unix, command-line

I want to retrieve more than one line of a text file, and processing lines.

Example :

```
$user = system('getent passwd') ."\n";
```

result exmple :

```
tcpdump:x:72:72::/:/sbin/nologin
guest:x:500:500:Guest User:/home/guest:/bin/bash
dovecot:x:97:97:Dovecot IMAP server:/usr/libexec/dovecot:/sbin/nologin
dovenull:x:495:488:Dovecots unauthorized user:/usr/libexec/dovecot:/sbin/nologin
sa-milt:x:494:487:SpamAssassin Milter:/var/lib/spamass-milter:/bin/bash
demo1:*:2417:100:albert DemoUn:/home/gir_net/demo1:/bin/bash
demo2:*:2418:100:alfred DemoDeux:/home/gir_net/demo2:/bin/bash
demo3:*:2419:100:alphonse DemoTrois:/home/gir_net/demo3:/bin/bash
demo4:*:2420:100:alcide DemoQuatre:/home/gir_net/demo4:/bin/bash
```

I want to retrieve the full line who have "/home/" in the result of command.
I try many solution, but it's doesn't work.

After I retrieve I want to extract somme information of the lines who contains "/home/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using regular expression:

```
$user = shell_exec('getent passwd');
preg_match_all('/\/home\/[^:]+/', $user, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $dir) {
    print $dir;
}

/* will print:
/home/guest
/home/gir_net/demo1
/home/gir_net/demo2
/home/gir_net/demo3
/home/gir_net/demo4
*/
```

**Update:**

If you want to display the full line, it will be easier to use string functions instead of regular expression.

```
$user = shell_exec('getent passwd');
$user = explode("\n", trim($user));
foreach ($user as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '/home/') !== FALSE) {
        echo $line."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, i see only : /home/gir_net/demo4, only the last. A var_dump($result) => array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(32) "/home/giron_net/demo6"
  }
}

Comment: I forgot that `system()` only return the last line. Try to use `$user = shell_exec('getent passwd');` to get the full output string.

Comment: Wow it's works, but match don't  return the full line who contains "/home/" but she begining at /home/. I don't have : demo1:*:2417:100:albert DemoUn:

Comment: Are you trying to get the full line or just the home directory?

Comment: full line who have "/home/". We can preg_match with ":*:" too

Comment: Wow, perfect, i understand, you extracting all the line in a tab, you through the lines an you search "/home/" <with the position strpos, if we find a line we display her !  But why "!==" and not "!=", only for the position ?

Answer (score 0):

Turn `$user` into [an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line) and [grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) it. About extracting, if you want some help you should give details. Anyway come back **after** trying what you can obtain with explode and grep.

Comment: I already try, but the result is an array with only the last line (demo4), demo1,2,3 or unrecognized...

Comment: see bsdnoobz comment; in general I avoid the use of system so I am not accustomed to its details; once you have all the lines, explode and grep should work

Comment: Yeah, we need to use "shell_exec" not system.