# Feeding a list of URLs from an HTML form to PHP array

Tags: php, html, api

I have a .php file which I will be using to submit requests to a certain API. This API will return information regarding certain domain URLs, such as the domains age, PageRank, etc.

The part of the PHP file which is responsible for feeding the API call URL with the domain names I'm interested in looks as follows:

```
$batchedDomains = array('www.example.com', 'www.cnn.com', 'www.apple.com');
```

What I would like to do is feed this array information through a very simple HTML form. My current HTML for the form looks as follows:

```
<form name="myform" action="apitest.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="check_submit" value="1" />

    URL List:<br /> 
    <textarea name="urls" rows="20" cols="60">Enter URLs</textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is what I would like to see happen: whenever I enter a list of domain URLs into the HTML form (one domain per line), I would like the  $batchedDomains array to be populated with those values.

Can anyone help me out with this? Or if you have a suggestion for a different solution I'm of course willing to hear it out.

I do not want this information printed anywhere, as it will simply be used by the php script to call the API and display the results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$urls = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['urls']), 'parse_url');
```

Or pass a custom callback with [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) + `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` for stricter checks

Comment: did you mean `array_map('parseurl', array_filter(...));`?

Comment: @billyonecan this solution works as expected... http://codepad.viper-7.com/DhRerI

Comment: @billyonecan: `array_map` would replace the item with the return value of `parse_url`. OP doesn't seem to want that. Actually he didn't ask for validation either :)

Comment: Ahh I see. The only thing with using that as a means of filtering is that it will very rarely return false (returns empty input, simple strings etc.) +1 for the use of `PHP_EOL` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just entering one per line, you can split the textarea string by newlines, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483501/2213444.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// has no error checking, you'll want to check that $_POST['urls'] exists
$textarea = explode("\r\n", $_POST['urls']);
print_r($textarea);

?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea name='urls' rows='20' cols='60'>
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

**[Working Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZqnYDK)**

Comment: Hi! why is the Print_r required here? since I do not want to print anything anywhere. I just want to populate the $batchedDomains array in my php file. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something though!

Comment: It's not required... It's just there to show you that the variable was populated with your urls.

Comment: Either way, thanks a lot - the first line explode("\r\n", $_POST['urls']); is enough and it's exactly what I wanted :) Thank you!