# Imploding $_POST values with comma

Tags: php, forms

I have a textarea in my form where user will enter data line by line. I am processing it using  `$_POST` . I have to separate each line by a comma while echoing it in php

the text area content like this

```
233
123
abf
4c2
```

I tried with below code

```
$array = array($_POST['devices']);
$device = implode(",", $array);

echo $device;
```

But it not showing commas between each value, rather I will get plain values like

```
233 123 abf 4c2
```

How can I show it like

```
233,123,abf,4c2
```

All above values are part of the text area,

Comment: is your input is defined as array `devices[]` ??

Comment: A textarea gets sent to the server as a simple string. it is NOT an array that you can implode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not split a string into an array simply by creating an `array()`.

You need to convert it to an array by splitting the lines:

```
$devices = preg_split('/\s+/', $_POST['devices']);
echo implode(',', $devices');
```

**Note:** You may want to [split strictly on line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line). But the above will get you started.

Comment: for that matter you could do `preg_replace('/\s+/', ',', $_POST['devices']);` and skip the implode

Answer (score 1):

No need to summon the power of regular expressions. You can simply implode the results of an explode.

```
$str = implode(",", explode("\n", $_POST['devices']));
```