# How to parse a multiple choice problems and solution into an array format?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

For example, I have something like

> The study of standards for what is right and what is wrong is called **_**.
>
> a. pure science
>
> b. applied science
>
> c. ethics
>
> d. technology
>
> ... unknown number of choices ...
>
> ANS: C

and I want to split it into

```
['The study of standards for what is right and what is wrong is called _____.',
'pure science',
'applied science',
'ethics',
'technology',

... as many array elements as there are choices ... 

'ANS: C']
```

Is there a single regex I can use that will work with an arbitrary number of choices?
If not, how would you go about doing this in either Javascript or PHP?

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be a line-break between each solution?

Comment: yep. javascript split() function with "\na.", "\nb.", "\nc." is what I'm doing right now, but it's a very static solution and I'm only checking up to "\ne.". I was hoping for something more dynamic.

Comment: what is original source? txt file? Is there any structure to it? Seems like a bit of a garbage-in-garbage-out problem based on format shown without some layout criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there guaranteed to be a line-break between each solution? **Yep**...

In [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) you can use one of the following solutions.

Using the `split` method you can do the following:

```
results = myString.split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

Using the `match()` method you can do the following, this will match the parts that are not linebreaks.

```
results = myString.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

In [php](/questions/tagged/php) you accomplish your desired task using one of the following solutions.

```
$wanted = preg_split('~\R+(?!$)~u', $data);
print_r($wanted);
```

See [`live working demo`](https://eval.in/60337)

`\R` matches a generic newline; that is, anything considered a linebreak sequence by Unicode. This includes all characters matched by `\v` (vertical whitespace) and the multi character sequence `\x0D\x0A`. To use properly you need to enable the `u` modifier. The `u` modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE and Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8.

I used a negative lookahead after with `$` (end of line) so that you are not including empty whitespace.

You can avoid using split and match using negation here.

```
$wanted = preg_match_all('~[^\r\n]+~', $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

See [`live working demo`](https://eval.in/60340)

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => The study of standards for what is right and what is wrong is called _.
    [1] => a. pure science
    [2] => b. applied science
    [3] => c. ethics
    [4] => d. technology
    [5] => ... unknown number of choices ...
    [6] => ANS: C
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest iterating each line, based on the EOL (`\r\n` or `\n`). Then you can check each line to see if it a Question or an Answer Item or the Answer. If you want it all in one array, you can use `array_push()`.

Also found this that might be helpful: [How to put string in array, split by new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line)

Basically just splitting each line into an array as mentioned:

`$array = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $string);`