# Converter string to array in PHP

Tags: php

same as title, i want converter string:

```
$str = "#0 C:\wamp\www\test\err\index.php(19): b('123')
#1 C:\wamp\www\test\err\index.php(27): a()
#2 {main}";
```

to array look like this:

```
$arr = array(
   0 => '#0 C:\wamp\www\test\err\index.php(19): b('123')',
   1 => '#1 C:\wamp\www\test\err\index.php(27): a()',
   2 => '#2 {main}',
);
```

i try using $arr = explode("\n", $str); but not working,

somebody can help me???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line

Comment: `but not working` is not how you describe what problems you ran into.

Comment: also, your input string is using double quotes and includes many occurrences of `\t` which will be treated as tab characters. Use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `preg_split`, which will take care of different formatted linebreaks:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $string);
```