# How to split string from mysql database into 2 parts using new line or end of line?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have a variable that gets set from a database field that may have multiple line breaks. I want some php code that splits the text from that variable into 2 separate variables (or a array with 2 values) using ONLY the first line break as the delimiter.

So you understand what I am trying to do, the database field the variable is coming from is a post message and I essentially want to use the first bit of text up to the first line break as the post title and everything after that as the post message.

An example would be as follows:

> $myvariable = "Do you believe what happened today?\nThis great big bus
>   almost ran me over. Then I jumped out of the way.\nThen something else
>   happened and it was more crazy.\nFinally I decide to go home and have
>   a nap because the day was just going too crazy.\nI like elephant
>   pants, the fit me\nSNUGG!";
>
> My new variables would become:
>
> $title_from_myvariable = "Do you believe what happened today?";
>
> $message_from_myvariable = "This great big bus almost ran me over.
>   Then I jumped out of the way.\nThen something else happened and it was
>   more crazy.\nFinally I decide to go home and have a nap because the
>   day was just going too crazy.\nI like elephant pants, the fit
>   me\nSNUGG!";

I have looked at a few ways to do this using \n as the delimiter and using explode, and I have looked at PHP_EOL using explode as well.

There are a few great threads about this like the following:

[How to put string in array, split by new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line)

[Explode PHP string by new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997336/explode-php-string-by-new-line)

The problem is if I use code like:

```
$new_array_with_new_variables = explode("\n", $myvariable);
```

or

```
$new_array_with_new_variables = explode("PHP_EOL", $myvariable);
```

I end up splitting **EVERY** new line into a variable...

Any suggestions super coders out there? I just can't figure this one out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do what you are looking for.

```
$new_array_with_new_variablesTMP = explode("\n", $myvariable);
$new_array_with_new_variables = array($new_array_with_new_variablesTMP[0]);
array_shift($new_array_with_new_variablesTMP);
array_push($new_array_with_new_variables, implode('\n', $new_array_with_new_variablesTMP));

print_r($new_array_with_new_variables);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Do you believe what happened today?
    [1] => This great big bus almost ran me over. Then I jumped out of the way.\nThen something else happened and it was more crazy.\nFinally I decide to go home and have a nap because the day was just going too crazy.\nI like elephant pants, the fit me\nSNUGG!
)
```

**See it live:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ff2eeb5fb73593a2baa6b6abd88878281ac9acf

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and the other answer?

Comment: I haven't tested the other answer out. It was posted after I answered and left the page. My solution works though. I know that. Good luck with your project

Comment: Thanks @SterlingBeason it works, but with one issue. I need all the linebreaks to remain a part of Array[1]. Any idea how I could accomplish that... Thanks so much for the help man!

Comment: Sure, fixed it. See it live here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ff2eeb5fb73593a2baa6b6abd88878281ac9acf

Comment: Thank You so much @SterlingBeason

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid approach.

```
<?php
$pieces = explode("\n", $myvariable);
$title_from_myvariable = $pieces[0];
$message_from_myvariable = implode("\n", array_slice($pieces, 1, count($pieces) - 1));
```