# Converting KML to Array in PHP

Tags: php, kml

I've got stuck when i'm trying to convert a `*.kml` file to array using `PHP` language.

**kml file** >> [`path.kml`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJN4qbQbyrVVUM4NjgxWlk4M0U/view?usp=sharing)

**code**

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXml($file);
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('kml', 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2');

    $result = array();
    $places = $xpath->evaluate('//kml:Placemark', NULL, FALSE);
    foreach ($places as $place) {
        $coord = $xpath->evaluate('string(kml:LineString/kml:coordinates)',$place, FALSE);
        $i = explode("\n", $coord);
        $result = array(
            'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(kml:name)', $place, FALSE),
            'coords' => explode("\n", $coord, count($i)
            )
        );
    }

    var_dump($result);
```

the problem is when i'm trying to explode the string using `newLine` delimeter, and the result is always like this 
[image]

whereas i want the result like this [image]

could anyone to help me for solve my problem ? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\r\n'` *(between single quotes)* is: - a literal backslash, the letter r, a literal backslash, and the letter n. It isn't a carriage return and a linefeed. Between single quotes, escape sequences are not interpreted.

Other thing: Are you sure that the newline sequence is CRLF? It can be also only LF (rarely only CR).

Whatever, Try with `"\r\n"` and if it doesn't work with `"\n"` *(between double quotes)*.

[About PHP strings.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: i've got update the code, and i have new problem with the result. You can see it on the updated question

Comment: @Adi: you need to learn the basics to solve the problem yourself, not to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There is different new line characters, not just `\r\n` - try using something like `preg_split ('/\R/', $string);` instead to catch all new line characters.

For a more detailed explanation of what `\R` does, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836692/1577453) SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the coords array:

```
<?php

function itemTrim(&$item) {
    $item = trim($item);
}

$r = "
     115.09031667,-8.81930500,64.500
     115.09031500,-8.81925667,64.400
     115.09033000,-8.81920167,64.300
     115.09038167,-8.81911333,64.100
     115.09042333,-8.81904000,64.000
     115.09048000,-8.81896833,63.900
     115.09053333,-8.81889167,63.800
     115.09056167,-8.81882333,63.800
     115.09059500,-8.81876667,63.800
     115.09063500,-8.81872500,63.900
     115.09067333,-8.81870167,63.800
    ";

$a = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $r);
$b = array_walk($a, "itemTrim");

var_dump($a);
```

But the considerations on the other answers about the line terminator is true, i used an regular expression from [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line).